# Java - getMessage() returns null

Tags: java

I'm trying to catch an exception then display it in a JTextArea but I am getting null...

Here it is:

```
} catch (Exception rwe) {
                  // System.exit(0);
                  game.remove(yPanel);
                  game.remove(xPanel);
                  game.remove(roomPanel);
                  game.remove(userPanel);
                  game.remove(titlePanel);
                  game.remove(introPanel);
                  remove(game);
                  remove(sp);
                  remove(invOne);
                  remove(main);
                  remove(say);
                  add(statusPanel);
                  JTextArea errorText = new JTextArea();
                  errorText.append("Here is the reason why it crashed:\n" +rwe.getMessage());
                  errorText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,300));
                  System.out.println("errorrr:" + rwe.getMessage());
                  statusPanel.add(errorText);

            statusPanel.setOpaque(true);
            labelStatus.setVisible(true);
                  System.out.println("Server crashed");
                  c.append("\nServer crashed...");
                  rwe.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and when an error happens I get this inside the JTextArea:

```
Here is the reason why it crashed:
null
```

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the exception `rwe` doesn't include a message. This is typically the case with a `NullPointerException`, for instance. You might want to include the exception type in addition to the message (if it has one).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to display the message of an exception in the JTextarea. An exception doesn't need to have a message. Maybe this doesn't.